# How can I get a cell value from grouped dataframe without the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am using a pandas `df.groupby()` function to group my dataframe on a column and iterate over it as follows:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                       'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                       'C' : np.random.randn(8),
                       'D' : np.random.randn(8)})

""" above df looks like this
     A      B         C         D
0  foo    one -0.575010 -0.271119
1  bar    one -0.130209 -0.106217
2  foo    two  0.093987 -1.351369
3  bar  three -0.403304  0.983619
4  foo    two  0.668989  0.249099
5  bar    two  1.153876  1.407159
6  foo    one  1.453793 -0.347721
7  foo  three  0.493562 -0.051688
"""

    grouped = df.groupby('A')

    for name, group in grouped:
        print(group)
        print(group['B'])
```

Here `print(group)` returns as follows:

```
     A      B         C         D
1  bar    one -0.130209 -0.106217
3  bar  three -0.403304  0.983619
5  bar    two  1.153876  1.407159
```

And `group['B']` returns

```
1      one
3    three
5      two
```

I want to get `one` and not the index 1 or 3 or 5 but just `one`, `three` and `two` which are column `B` values.

Here `iloc` won't work as indexes aren't continuous and I won't know which index is coming while iterating over the grouped dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `df.to_string` with `index=False`:

```
for _, g in df.groupby('A'):
     print(g['B'].to_string(index=False))
```

This prints out a series but without the accompanying index. Alternatively, use `g['B'].tolist()`, if you want a list of values.

Answer (score 1):

Try `group['B'].values`.

This will return the elements of the series as a numpy array.